# Not able to retrieve RedShift cluster Capacity details like Storage, Memory using Python script

Tags: amazon-redshift

I have tried to fetch my RedShift cluster details. I'm able to see many details about the cluster but few details got missed.

For Ex:- Details like **Storage**and **Memory**

The below is the code:-

```
redshiftClient = boto3.client('redshift', aws_access_key_id = role.credentials.access_key,
    aws_secret_access_key = role.credentials.secret_key, aws_session_token = role.credentials.session_token, region_name='us-west-2')

#Getting all the clusters
clusters = redshiftClient.describe_clusters()
```

can you please check provide the way to get it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [describe-clusters](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/redshift/describe-clusters.html) command does not return that type of information. The output of that command is:

```
{
   "Clusters": [
   {
      "NodeType": "dw.hs1.xlarge",
      "Endpoint": {
         "Port": 5439,
         "Address": "mycluster.coqoarplqhsn.us-east-1.redshift.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "ClusterVersion": "1.0",
      "PubliclyAccessible": "true",
      "MasterUsername": "adminuser",
      "ClusterParameterGroups": [
         {
            "ParameterApplyStatus": "in-sync",
            "ParameterGroupName": "default.redshift-1.0"
         } ],
      "ClusterSecurityGroups": [
         {
            "Status": "active",
            "ClusterSecurityGroupName": "default"
         } ],
      "AllowVersionUpgrade": true,
      "VpcSecurityGroups": \[],
      "AvailabilityZone": "us-east-1a",
      "ClusterCreateTime": "2013-01-22T21:59:29.559Z",
      "PreferredMaintenanceWindow": "sat:03:30-sat:04:00",
      "AutomatedSnapshotRetentionPeriod": 1,
      "ClusterStatus": "available",
      "ClusterIdentifier": "mycluster",
      "DBName": "dev",
      "NumberOfNodes": 2,
      "PendingModifiedValues": {}
   } ],
   "ResponseMetadata": {
      "RequestId": "65b71cac-64df-11e2-8f5b-e90bd6c77476"
   }
}
```

You will need to retrieve Memory and Storage statistics from Amazon CloudWatch.

See your other question: [Amazon CloudWatch is not returning Redshift metrics](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43523173/174777)

If you actually want to retrieve information about a standard cluster (that is, the amount of storage and memory assigned to each node, rather than current memory and storage usage), that is not available from an API call. Instead see: [Amazon Redshift Clusters](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/working-with-clusters.html)

Comment: Thanks. Got it :)

Comment: Hi @srikanth, if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.